# Are firebase database listeners optimised for identical and parent-child paths?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Take the following listeners:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref.child('users').onValue()... 
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref.child('users').onValue()...
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref.child('users/1').onValue()...
```

How many times is the data read from the database?

Comment: I'm not sure why would you attach a listener on `users/1` since when you're listening to the `users` node, you have already downloaded all the data under the `users` node, including user `1`.

Comment: @AlexMamo I got a master detail view. A user gets passed down to the detail. I want the screen to change on any change to the user. I could try to create some state object for the user, but creating a listener would be much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If they're all active at the same time, the first two listeners will only lead to a single read of the data from the server. The SDK deduplicates the data transfer for those behind the scenes.

I'm not 100% of the third listener though. I don't recall ever using overlapping listeners, as it typically points to a mistake in my data structure, or a mismanagement of listeners in my code.